# ngx-infinite-scroll: Unable to trigger (scrolled) event

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

There is one parent component whose name is "chat.component". Inside that component, there are 3 other component: Header, Messages and Message-Input components. I want to implement Ngx-Infinite scroll under Messages component. So for that I have implement following html and scss design.

chat.component.html:

```
<div class="chat-container px-md-0" *ngIf="!appService.loading">
  <app-chat-header
    [ngClass]="{ blurred: isUserDisconnected }"
  ></app-chat-header>
  <app-messages
      [ngClass]="{ blurred: isUserDisconnected }"
  ></app-messages>
  <app-message-input
    [ngClass]="{ blurred: isUserDisconnected }"
  ></app-message-input>
</div>
```

chat.component.scss:

```
.chat-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid var(--border-clr);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 50vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 85vh;

  app-chat-header {
    width: 100%;
  }

  app-messages {
    flex: 1;
    // overflow-y: auto; /* Add scrollbar if needed */
    width: 100%;
  }

  app-message-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

messages.component.html:

```
<section class="messages-section">
    <div
      class="messages-container"
      infiniteScroll
      [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
      (scrolled)="onScrolled()"
    >
      <ng-container *ngIf="messageList.length !== 0">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let message of messageList">
          <div
            class="message"
            [class.sent-message]="isSentMessage(message)"
            [class.received-message]="!isSentMessage(message)"
          >
            {{ message.content }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
</section>
```

messages.component.scss:

```
@import "../../../assets/styles/scss/variables.scss";

.messages-section {
  height: 100%;

    .messages-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      .message {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 70%;
      }

      .sent-message {
        align-self: flex-end !important;
        background-color: var(--blue);
        color: var(--white);
      }

      .received-message {
        align-self: flex-start !important;
        background-color: var(--dark-grey);
        color: var(--white);
      }
    }
}
```

Now, In the chat.component.scss if I put overflow-y: auto then (scrolled) event for ngx-infinite-scroll is not working for messages.component.scss and if I removed that overflow-y then it is taking Windows scrolls and working well. So how to achieve this scenario if i put overflow-y: auto in chat.component.scss then in messages.component (scrolled) event should work. Please help me out in this scenario. Along with this, also want to integrate ngx-scrollbar.

For ngx-infinite-scroll, there is one attribute [scrollWindow]="false" which I tried setting it with inside the div tag messages component along with overflow-y=auto to show a scroll bar but it is not working.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).